# VC++ marco, getting raw text of parameter

Tags: c++, macros

How do I get the text of the data given to `value`, not the value of the executed expression?

```
#define PRINT_VALUE(value) std::cout << "Value " << __RAWTEXT(value) << " is " << value << "\n";
```

`__RAWTEXT` is something I made up. Is there really something out there that does this though?

```
int testVariable = 5;
PRINT_VALUE(testVariable);
```

The output of this should be

> Value testVariable  is 5

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "stringize" operator `#` for this:

```
#define PRINT_VALUE(value) std::cout << "Value " << #value << " is " << value << "\n";
```

It's pretty straightforward, `#TTT` in a macro converts `TTT` to `"TTT"`, a string literal.

---

It's worth mentioning that when the parameter is *itself* a macro, you'll get the name of the macro.  However, if the parameter is passed to a subsequent macro, it's "unpacked".  So you see these sometimes:

```
#define STRINGIZE2(X) #X
#define STRINGIZE(X) STRINGIZE2(X)
```

Here they are in action:

```
#define TEST Bob
std::cout << #TEST; //results in "TEST"
std::cout << STRINGIZE2(TEST); //results in "TEST"
std::cout << STRINGIZE(TEST); //results in "Bob"
```

---

Not relevent to your question but also notable is the "concat" macro operator `##` which "glues" two bits of text togeather.   `std::st ## ing` results in `std::string`.  Useful in macros:

```
 #define make_thing(X) \
 structX##_class {
     static const char* const name=#X;
 };
 make_thing(Foo);
 std::cout << Foo_class::name;
```

And again, if a parameter is a macro, you get the macro name.  So here's the de-macro macros:

```
#define GLUE2(X,Y) (X##Y)
#define GLUE(X,Y) GLUE2(X,Y)

#define HEY "HELLO"
#define THERE "WORLD"
std::cout << GLUE(HEY,THERE); //"HELLOWORLD"
```